# 4 people apply for 3 jobs; what's the probability that I will get a job?

Tags: probability

There are 4 people being interviewed for a job, one of them being me. There are 3 jobs. What is the probability of me getting a job? I think it's 75%.

Comment: If we assume that the interview doesn't make any difference, and the picking of people is done by tossing fair coins, then your answer is correct. Also, if the applicants look bad enough, one might simply not hire.

Comment: In the case that you are none of the four people, the chances are $0$. In the case that you are married to the CEO's daughter, I'd say the job is yours.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a probability question as your ability to do the job and your ability to sell yourself at the interview will take part.

For example if you call you prospective new boss a moron the probability of getting the job is going to be close to zero.

If one or more of the other applicants insults the new boss and you don't then the probability of you getting the job will be higher.

But, If we assume the interview is not taken into account and the new employees are chosen at random then yes the probability would be $\frac{3}{4}$ or 75%.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $3$ jobs, $A$, $B$ and $C$, and $4$ applicants $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, then there are $4 \times 3 \times 2=24$ possible ways of assigning people to jobs (assuming each applicant can only receive one job).

- There are $4$ ways to assign an employee to job $A$.
- Once job $A$ has been assigned, there are $3$ ways to assign an employee to job $B$.
- Once jobs $A$ and $B$ have been assigned, there are $2$ ways to assign an employee to job $C$.

Using an argument similar to the above, we see there are $3 \times 2=6$ ways of assigning people so that applicant $a$ receives job $A$.  Similarly, for jobs $B$ and $C$.

Hence, the probability that applicant $a$ receives a job is $$\frac{3 \times 6}{24}=\frac{3}{4}=75\%.$$

Note that the above assumes each possible outcome (of the $24$ possible outcomes) has equal probability of occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to know if they’re hiring 3 people and 4 people apply what’s his or her probability..

Applicants that can fill the 3 spots when all spots are still open:
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,4
2,3,4

Each number appears 3 times in 4 different arrangements. 3/4. 75%

Say the first spot is filled by applicant 1.. (you are number 4)

2 openings left and 3 applicants to choose from.
Arrangements of applicants for the number 2 spot:
2,3
2,4
3,4

Each number appears 2 times in the 3 arrangements. 2/3. 66 percent chance you fill the second slot.

Obviously it’s 50 percent for the last slot.

I don’t know if you can average probability outcomes?? Lemme know because if you can, your overall probability to get a job in this situation would be 63.6%

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).